# How do I color code calculated values in a SharePoint List (same column) that is greater than X?

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have SharePoint Designer 2013 and I am new to SharePoint / SharePoint Designer 2013

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the calculated fields have different color based on their values? such as if the value is greater than X, we make it green.

if so, you may consider using Client Side Rendering, add some JS script to the page to achieve the goal.

- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it . Add a div tag inside your calculated coloun and add some color like green, yellow and red .. and add your condition ..next bind the return value to the div ..